# Inheriting class not seeing base class

Tags: class, inheritance, f#, undefined

I have an abstract class in one file:

```ml
namespace Dac.V5

[<AbstractClass>]
type DacRecord(recordType: int16) =
    do
        if recordType < 0s then
            invalidArg (nameof recordType) "Argument out of range"

    member this.Type = recordType
```

and an inheriting class in an adjacent file:

```ml
namespace Dac.V5

[<AbstractClass>]
type DacReturnRecord(recordType: int16, decodedData: byte seq) =
    inherit DacRecord(recordType)

    let data: byte seq = decodedData

    member this.Data with get() = data and set(v) = data <- v
```

However, in the inheriting class, the base class appears undefined, and I get an error on the `inherit` statement.

The files are in the same subdirectory, and are named after the classes they hold.

Comment: In what order are the files listed in your .fsproj file? The file containing the derived class must appear after the file containing the base class. I suspect you have them in the opposite order.

Comment: That's a strange requirement; I don't believe C# behaves that way. Is that really necessary?

Comment: F# requires code to be in dependency order. That is, you cannot use forward references to code that hasn’t been seen by the compiler yet. This is a common hurdle for folks moving from C# to F#. I was annoyed by it at first as well, but came to see it as a reasonable decision. You can find a good explanation [here](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/cyclic-dependencies/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to order the files so that the base class comes before the inherited one. Once you do this, it should work, except that you need to mark `data` as `mutable`:

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type DacReturnRecord(recordType: int16, decodedData: byte seq) =
    inherit DacRecord(recordType)

    let mutable data: byte seq = decodedData

    member this.Data with get() = data and set(v) = data <- v
```

Comment: Yes, that was the solution. It's still puzzling, regardless.